# Rails Method To Sum Based on Criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3 Ruby 1.9

My app has a shopping cart and the following models  line_items, order, and products. The Products model has 2 price attributes msrp and discount_price  the line_items model has a product_price attribute

I am trying to write a helper method that takes a product_id, traverse all completed orders, and select and sum the line items where product_price = msrp.

My Products Model

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :line_items
 has_many :orders, through: :line_items

 end
```

My Orders Model

```
 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

 end
```

My Line_Items Model

```
 class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base  

 belongs_to :order
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :cart

 def self.total_sold_msrp(product)
 where("line_items.order_id IS NOT NULL AND line_items.product_id = product.id AND line_items.product_price = product.msrp")
 end


 end
```

Helper Module

```
 module StoreHelper

 def full_price_qty_sold (product)
 full_price_qty_sold = product.line_items.total_sold_msrp(product).sum("quantity")
 end

 end
```

When I execute the program I get this error 
     "SQLException: no such column: product.id product.msrp"

It looks like the app is looking for columns named product.id and product.msrp as opposed to using the actual values of product.id and product.msrp when it queries the  SQL table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It looks like the app is looking for columns named product.id and product.msrp as opposed to using the actual values of product.id and product.msrp when it queries the SQL table.

Exactly. The correct way to pass values to the query would be

```
 where("line_items.order_id IS NOT NULL AND line_items.product_id = ? AND line_items.product_price = ?", product.id, product.msrp)
```